# Woocommerce product api not accept images in some urls

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, product

I am creating products from external in woocommerce site. My code is like bellow:

```
if($_POST["Type"] == "CREATE"){
         $data = array(
            'product' => array(
                'title' => $_POST["Title"],
                'type' => 'simple',
                'regular_price' => $_POST["Regular_price"],
                'description' => $_POST["Description"],
                'short_description' => $_POST["Short_description"],
                'categories' => array(
                    $_POST['CategoryName']
                ),
                'images' => array(
                    array(
                        'src' => $_POST["Image_url"],
                        'position' => 0
                    ),
                    array(
                        'src' => $_POST["Image_url"],
                        'position' => 1
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    $res = $client->products->create($data);
}
```

When using `$_POST["Image_url"]` such like http://app.test.net:8080/test/img/company-logo.png gives the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception' with message 'Error: Error getting remote image
```

But if we give a normal url(url do not contain the specific port) such like http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/test.png it's working properly.

How to resolve this?

Comment: i have tested only for the product.Also debug the api in the server side can't find the error.

Comment: no using original theme directly.Theme name is Blanco

Comment: my images in separate web server running on port 8080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case above mentioned code in the such a URL (http://app.test.net:8080/api/v1/product.php). Calling this API from .net application by (http://appname.test.net). Both are having the same domain part (**test.net**).

There fore difficult to find the URL to woo commerce.I have change URL the of .net application by my server configuration(I have using virtual hosts).Then it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

---- *(Edit 2)* ----

Sorry but your question is Not clear at all. You have to update it, because it is very incomplete and fuzzy. Same thing for the title.

The medias images are located in a 2nd server on port 8080, right…

Form me the problem is here in:

```
'images' => array(
    array(
        'src' => $_POST["Image_url"],
        'position' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'src' => $_POST["Image_url"],
        'position' => 0
    )
)
```

with `'src' => $_POST["Image_url"]`

Have a look to this interesting related thread: [Synchronize external database with woocommerce database](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/synchronize-external-database-with-woocommerce-database)

Comment: I have added those two lines but not working same error existing.My images are not in the woo-commerce ( word press) server.They are in separate server.

Comment: I have a .net application.There are products in that application.In hear i'm sinking those products to the woocommerce. There for images are in external server.Sending a woocommerce api request to create same product in the woocommerce from .net side.

Comment: But when creating from another server(mean .net application contain server) image get correctly in my code.Only if there is a port containing in the url It do not take(giving error).If remove 'images' => array( part and put    'src' => $_POST["Image_url"]    product creating successfully.But image do not take It get woocommerce default image as a product image.

Comment: Yes i want to replicate .net application product in woocommerce.

Comment: This thread is relating the same kind of problem you have: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213214/integrate-product-feed-api-in-woocommerce

Comment: Very happy for you! How? i am a bit curious… :)

Comment: When i send the URL in same port as the word press it try to find the image inside the woo comers.It do not try to get the URL from the external one.What i have done is change the URL name and port by the server configuration.Now working properly